# how to create a new directory in application server

Tags: directory, abap

i want make a new directory in application server in sap system ,and send my file in it .
for sending file in existing directory i find and use this transaction

CG3Z :/usr/sap/R3D/exe .

But i can not find a solution , neither with transaction nor abap codes .
I know that we can see directory with AL11 but I want to make my own directory.
I searched in SAP SCN and Stackoverflow but have not been able to find any similar problem.

Comment: ...and as a further recomendation, I would remove the irrelevant whiny part at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is NOT done by application code but by a system administrator - otherwise you would have to add provisions for all supported operating systems. Also, there are a lot of other issues to take care of, like setting the proper file system permissions or making sure that a DFS is available on all application servers (writing stuff to application servers randomly depending on which server the user was logged on to usually won't do you any good). Have your system administrator setup a [logical file name](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/2a/fa0290493111d182b70000e829fbfe/content.htm) for you and use that.